# Delete object after setting property

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have a class called 'School' whoch includes methods that perform actions on the 'pupils' object which is a property of the class.

I also have three HTML forms which allow you to add a pupil, delete a pupil and set a particular property to a pupil.

They all work except for this condition: if I set a pupil property and then attempt to delete that same pupil, it does not work. This error is logged to console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at School.findPupilProperty ((index):59)
>       at HTMLFormElement.delPupil ((index):195)

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, pupils) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.pupils = pupils;
  }
  getPupil(name) {
    name = this.nameUpperCase(name);
    let pupil = this.pupils.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
    return pupil;
  }
  getPupilsByProperty(property, value) {
    let pupilArray = this.pupils.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.property === value;
    });
    return pupilArray;
  }
  findPupilProperty(property, value, find) {
    if (property === 'name') {
      value = this.nameUpperCase(value);
    }
    let desired_pupil = this.pupils.find(function(obj) {
      return obj[property] === value;
    });
    return desired_pupil[find];
  }
  generateNewPupilID() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.pupils.length; i++) {
      if (i === this.pupils.length - 1) {
        return this.pupils[i].id + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  addPupil(name, age, grades = [], attendance = 0) {
   // name = this.nameUpperCase(name);
    let id = this.generateNewPupilID();
    this.pupils.push({
      id: id,
      name: name,
      age: age,
      grades: grades,
      attendance: attendance
    });
  }
  deletePupil(name) {
    name = this.nameUpperCase(name);
    let pupil = this.pupils.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
    let index = this.pupils.findIndex(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
    this.pupils.splice(index, 1);
  }
  nameUpperCase(name) {
   name = name.split(' ');
    let first_name_arr = name[0].split('');
    let last_name_arr  = name[1].split('');
    for(let i = 0; i < first_name_arr.length; i++) {
     if(i === 0) {
       first_name_arr[0] = first_name_arr[0].toUpperCase();
      } else {
       first_name_arr[i] = first_name_arr[i].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    for(let x = 0; x < last_name_arr.length; x++) {
     if(x === 0) {
       last_name_arr[0] = last_name_arr[0].toUpperCase();
      } else {
       last_name_arr[x] = last_name_arr[x].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    let strname =  first_name_arr.join('') + ' ' + last_name_arr.join('');
    return strname;
 }
  
  setPupilProperty(name, property, value) {
    name = this.nameUpperCase(name);
    let pupil = this.pupils.find(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
    property = property.toLowerCase();
    pupil[property] = value;
  }
  getGradesByPupil(name, subject) {
    this.pupils.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (obj.name === name) {
        if (!subject) {
          return obj.grades;
        } else {
          return obj.grades.subject;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

let pupils = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 17,
    grades: {
      'English': 9,
      'Maths': 9,
      'Sociology': 'A*'
    },
    attendance: 12
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 17,
    grades: {
      'English': 7,
      'Maths': 6,
      'Sociology': 'B'
    },
    attendance: 92
  }
];

const school = new School('somethingschool', 'high', pupils);

function displayPupil(obj) {
  document.getElementById('pupils').innerHTML +=
    `
  <div id=pupil-${obj.id}>
  <h3>${obj.name}</h3>
  <p>ID: ${obj.id}</p>
  <p>Age: ${obj.age}</p>
  <p>Attendance: ${obj.attendance}</p>
  </div>
  `;
}

school.pupils.forEach(function(obj) {
  displayPupil(obj);
});

document.getElementById('addpupil').addEventListener('submit', addPupil);
document.getElementById('delpupil').addEventListener('submit', delPupil);
document.getElementById('setprop').addEventListener('submit', setProp);

function addPupil(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('addpupil');
  var name = school.nameUpperCase(form.name.value);
  var age = form.age.value;
  school.addPupil(name, age);
  var pupil = school.getPupil(name);
  displayPupil(pupil);
}

function delPupil(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('delpupil');
  var name = form.name.value;
  console.log(name);
  var id = school.findPupilProperty('name', name, 'id');
  school.deletePupil(name);
  document.getElementById('pupil-' + id).innerHTML = '';
}

function setProp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('setprop');
  var name = form.name.value;
  var prop = form.prop.value;
  var value = form.value.value;
  var id = school.findPupilProperty('name', name, 'id');
  school.setPupilProperty(name, prop, value);
  document.getElementById('pupil-' + id).innerHTML = '';
  displayPupil(school.getPupil(name));
}
```

```html
<div id='pupils'>

</div>

<h2>
  Functions
</h2>
<h3>
  Add Pupil
</h3>
<form id='addpupil'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br/> Age: <input type='text' name='age'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<h3>
  Delete Pupil
</h3>
<form id='delpupil'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<h3>
  Set Pupil Property
</h3>

<form id='setprop'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br/> Property: <input type='text' name='prop'><br/> Value: <input type='text' name='value'><br/>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Can anybody figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just add your code to a code snippet, right here in your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I disagree. A Fiddle/JSBin/Codepen, etc link can add to a post, and make it easier for readers to fiddle than can snippets.  Of course any code deemed relevant should still be included in the question, and if it's small enough should be in a runnable snippet.  But such a link is not at all harmful.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Because of `return desired_pupil[find];` at the end of `findPupilProperty`,

When the `.find()` can't find the pupil, it return `undefined` and you're basically returning `undefined['id']` resulting in the error,

you should add a check for that like replacing

`return desired_pupil[find];`

with

`return desired_pupil ? desired_pupil[find] : null;`

`null` is just a suggestion, return the proper value you need afterwards.

Comment: I added that code and it is now returning null. But that's the thing: it shouldn't be. I am entering a pupil that does exist and should be found by the function.